# How to transform geometry in django rest framework gis

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postgis, geodjango, django-rest-framework-gis

I am newbie to Django and developing a REST API using Django Rest Framework (DRF) and GIS. Previously, I was using an SQL query for transforming a geometry:

```sql
select
    id, 
    name, 
    round(value::numeric, 2) as value,
    st_transform(geometry, 3857) as geometry
from
    my_model
```

...

```python
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
    geometry = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        db_table = u'my_model'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

Here serializer class:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.GeoModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'value', 'geometry')
```

I have also tried to do this way but cannot transform output

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all().transform(3857)
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

How can I do this in Django Rest Framework and GIS? Where can I get query sample or a comprehensive tutorial for DRF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

Add the **srid** argument to transform function. I was considering as

> transform(srid)

first argument as srid but should be like this

> transform(srid=3857)

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all().transform(srid=3857)
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Comment: This gives me: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'transform'` where does function `transform()` comes from? do you have related docs?

Comment: Maybe, this can help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.transform

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94640/geodjango-transform-not-working

Comment: But as I understand (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48840336/5804947) the `transform()` function has been deprecated and replaced by database function [`Transform`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Transform), correct?
But then I cannot use answer given above as annotations dont work with `GeoModelSerializer` (see my issue https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis/issues/250)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a default SRID to your `GeometryField` -

```
geometry = models.GeometryField(srid=3857, null=True, blank=True)
```

And Django will automatically handle the conversion. More details on [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#srid) and [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#automatic-spatial-transformations).

> Where can i get queries sample or comprehensive tutorial for rest framework gis?

You can find all about geodjango on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/). Django rest framework is noting but Django.