# Cannot find the GeoManager in module django.contrib.gis.db. models in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am working on a GeoDjango project(first time working in a web app). Tring to use GeoManager but an error pops out saying `module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute 'GeoManager'`. After that, I checked the [release notes of Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/) and found out that the  `GeoManager`and `GeoQuerySet` classes are removed in Django 2.0.

Does anyone know which module is it in right now? Or can anyone suggest any better alternative

Answer (score 2):

They were deprecated in Django 1.9 as there are now functions that are replacing them.

From [1.9 changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.9/#django-contrib-gis)

> All GeoQuerySet methods have been deprecated and replaced by
>   [equivalent database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/functions/). As soon as the legacy methods have been
>   replaced in your code, you should even be able to remove the special
>   GeoManager from your GIS-enabled classes.

Comment: Can default manager in Django 2.0 handle spatial queries? I don't need to override it?

Comment: @Enigma have you seen documentation that I have attached (equivalent database functions)? Think that usage is self explanatory