# I got this Error AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute 'GeoManager'

Tags: django, model, migrate, makemigrations

```
This Is My Models : 

class Intervention(models.Model):
        Titre_intervention = models.TextField(max_length=255)
        date_intervention = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        type_panne = models.ForeignKey(Panne,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        etat = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
        image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='medial/%Y/%m/%D')
        equipements = models.ManyToManyField(Equipement)
        clients = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
        location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
        objects = models.GeoManager()
```

And This Is What I Imports :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

So When I Run Makemigrations I got error Of :

> AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute
>   'GeoManager'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find the GeoManager in module django.contrib.gis.db. models in Django 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839817/cannot-find-the-geomanager-in-module-django-contrib-gis-db-models-in-django-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoManager has been removed.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)

A workaround that appears to function correctly:

Import in your models file:

```
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager
```

In your model class:

```
objects = GeoManager()
```